# Uppercase inside ng-disabled

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to enable a delete button by forcing a user to type the word 'DELETE' into a text input.  The code below works however it's case sensitive, meaning that if someone for example types 'delete' it will not work.

Can anyone advise how I would need to change the code below to make it case insensitive?

```
 <div ng-app="">
  <div ng-controller="test">
  <label>Type the word DELETE below to confirm</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="TYPE DELETE" ng-model="deletetext" /> <br />
  <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-disabled="deletetext != 'DELETE'">DELETE</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `deletetext.toUpperCase() != 'DELETE'`? And if angular does not allow that, try moving it into a controller function. `hasTypedDelete()`

Comment: Thanks Thilo, I thought I'd tried the toUpperCase() before but I must of got something wrong as I've just tried it again and it works perfectly.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Thilo's suggestion of using deletetext.toUpperCase() != 'DELETE' fixed this issue.  This corrected code now looks like this

```
<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-controller="test">
  <label>Type the word DELETE below to confirm</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="TYPE DELETE" ng-model="deletetext" /> <br />
  <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-disabled="deletetext.toUpperCase() != 'DELETE'>DELETE</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`deletetext.toUpperCase() != 'DELETE'` works. You can also add a $watch to `deletetext` and force it to be upper case.It is better usability IMO.

```
$scope.$watch('deletetext', function(newValue, oldValue){
    $scope.deletetext = newValue.toUpperCase();
});
```

Here is the full example:
http://jsfiddle.net/GLCAT/